# angular-ui-router always redirects to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my **Angular SPA** application, when type the address into the address bar or click on `ui-sref` link, I am always redirected to the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`. My Code is given below:

```
  angular.module('gamopot-app', [ 'ui.router' ] )
      .config(function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {
          // always redirect to here 
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

          // Home state routing
          $stateProvider
              .state('home', {
                  url: '/home',
                  templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.ejs',
                  controller: 'IndexCtrl'
              })
               // won't work for http://localhost:3000/#/game
              .state('game', {
                  url: '/game',
                  templateUrl: 'modules/game/client/views/list-games.client.view.ejs',
                  controller: 'GameIndexCtrl'
               })
               // won't work for http://localhost:3000/#/demo
              .state('demo', {
                  url: '/demo',
                  templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/demo.home.client.view.ejs',
                  controller: 'DemoIndexCtrl'
               });
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="gamopot-app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
             <!--<ui-view></ui-view>-->
              <div ui-view></div>
         </div>       
     </body>
</html>
```

**modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.ejs**

```
  <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
       <!-- main index view -->
  </div>
```

**modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.ejs**

```
  <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
       <!-- main index view -->
  </div>
```

**modules/core/client/views/demo.home.client.view.ejs**

```
   <div ng-controller="DemoIndexCtrl">
       <h1>{{test_demo}}</h1>
   </div>
```

**modules/game/client/views/list-games.client.view.ejs**

```
  <div ng-controller="GameIndexCtrl">
    <h1> {{test_game}} </h1>
  </div>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you give a sample for an address you are using?

Comment: provide html code to know more about issue ?

Comment: What is missing is rather the main page, i.e. index.html. But your templates are all wrong: you shouldn't have ng-controller inside, since the controller is already specified in the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I also had this kind of problem. I don't know where is the problem, but I think I can solve this problem. Here is my solution:

```
angular.module('gamopot-app', [ 'ui.router' ] )
   .config(function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) {

         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

         $stateProvider
             .state('home', {
                 url: '/home',   // now http://localhost:3030/home will work
                  templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.ejs',
                  controller: 'IndexCtrl'
             })

             // the rest code would be same
             ...............................
             .................................
       });
```

I hope it would be a solution for your problem.

**NB:** still in this code, there are some problem, such as:

when you type in your browser address bar `http://localhost:3030/home` and hit enter, it directly make a **server request**, not **angular route request**. you can use `ui-sref`.